# Applying multiple action in Cart Price Rules

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

Is it possible to create multiple action for price rules?
Like I am setting a 5% Discounts for customers but the discount is capped at $250.00 When the purchased is greater than $5000.00?
Is this possible?
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Its not possible to set Limit for Maximum discount amount in case of setting discount in percent (%).

You can check `applyRule` function in `Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier` class to extend this for your requirement.