# Multiple Actions using two shopping cart rules with the same coupon code? still possible in 2.3.2?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I read in these two threads that seem dated on the status of this functionality on Magento.

[Multiple actions on shopping cart price rule](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16111/multiple-actions-on-shopping-cart-price-rule)
[Applying multiple action in Cart Price Rules](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/323244/applying-multiple-action-in-cart-price-rules)

Is it still possible to have a single coupon code apply a percentage discount and a specific item for free using two shopping cart rules that have the same coupon code?

Answer (score 0):

With a clean Magento install (OOTB 2.4.1 open source), you will have the following error raised when trying to save a cart rule having the same coupon code as other rule - ***"Coupon with the same code already exists."***

So unless there is a 3rd party module or other customizations done, this is not possible.